# Blazor Cannot find declaration of exported type System.Threading.Semaphore from the assembly System.Threading

Tags: c#, linker, blazor

When building my Blazor app (ASP.NET Core Hosted, i.e., client/server/shared) (Blazor V3.0.0 Preview 6 19307.2) that now includes Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (V2.2.6), I get the error in the verbose build output:

> Cannot find declaration of exported type System.Threading.Semaphore
>   from the assembly System.Threading

I'm guessing the error came up because I'm now using an async task to get EF data via JSON:

```
Employee[] empList;
protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
{
empList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Employee[]>
   ("/api/Employee/Index");
}
```

Note that I received an MSB3073 in the error list originally, and got the above error after I'd enabled verbose output for the build.

I double-checked all the nuget files, and used last stable entity framework core instead of the latest preview version (the latest preview version gave an error in the build).

I want the build to skip linking to System.Threading.Semaphore.

Comment: Do tell us which Blazor this is: server-side or webassembly, which preview version.

Comment: I edited the question to include that information.

Comment: I've upgraded Entity Framework to preview6 but still get the same error and still need the same fix below.

Answer (score 2):

I included the following in my blazor client csproj file, in the  section:

```
<BlazorLinkOnBuild>false</BlazorLinkOnBuild>
```

I found this on another website:

https://blog.negativeeddy.com/2019/05/03/blazorbot/

but have posted it here, to make it easier to find

Comment: This isn't an answer, and should be deleted and instead edited into your question above using the `edit` link.

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer - no it is an answer and this self answer pattern is OK.

Comment: you can update to indicate the section to add it in is the main property group, i.e, containing the `<TargetFramework>` tag.